# SSH server on Python

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko, twisted.conch

I need a simple example of a ssh server on python. I do not know much English, I find it difficult to understand the documentation. I tried to use paramiko and twisted conch. Help me, please. I find [this](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/conch/examples/), but documentation does not describe the things associated with ssh. I will be grateful if you could just comment [this](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/conch/examples/sshsimpleserver.py) example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't really believe an SSH server will ever be 'simple'. But I did get an SSH honeypot running a while back using python 2.7 on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Server. You can see the code to it with my changes at

https://github.com/hydrogen18/kojoney

It uses twisted.